# Folium problem jupyter notebook: it doesn't show colors on map

Tags: python, jupyter, folium, choropleth

When display a map using folium with archive json and csv with dates it doesn't show colors after display, only one

code:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

mapa = folium.Map(location=[23.282, -101.47], zoom_start=5)
folium.GeoJson('nayarit.json').add_to(mapa)

df = pd.read_csv ('pobreza.csv') 

print(df)



    municipios  pobreza
0               La Yesca     79.4
1             Rosamorada     49.7
2              Huajicori     88.2
3       Amatlán de Cañas     49.5
4            Ahuacatlan|     39.7
5              Del Nayar     86.9
6                Xalisco     26.8
7    Santa María del Oro     37.2
8   San Pedro Lagunillas     48.1
9      Bahía de Banderas     26.6
10            Compostela     41.7
11        Ixtlán del Río     47.6
12             Acaponeta     51.1
13    Santiago Ixcuintla     45.5
14                Tuxpan     49.6
15                  Ruiz     61.1
16              San Blas     52.2
17                 Tepic     24.2
18               Tecuala     51.7
19                  Jala     70.6

geo="nayarit.json"
```

> ##access to file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BW5xhT3-kawl24EJ7b8DDDkAJc470qD0/view?usp=sharing

```
geo_poverty="pobreza.csv"
dates=pd.read_csv(geo_poverty)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geo,
    name="choropleth",
    data=dates,
    columns=["municipios", "pobreza"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="YlGn",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=.1,
    legend_name="Taza de pobreza (%)",
).add_to(mapa)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(mapa)

mapa
```

[display of a map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k9f9.png)

Comment: I think the reason is that the contents of the JSON file you are using are not configured into polygons by municipality. The basic mechanism is that the JSON file has the name of the municipality in this case as the id, and the polygon information for that municipality is in a continuous format. The id is linked to the name of the municipality in the data, and the data is filled in in conjunction with the value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using another JSON file, I'll let you know friend.

Comment: Dear friend, in this part of the code: key_on ="feature.ide"   was incorrect, so I changed to key_on="properties.nomgeo" ..... it works fine